# Clicking a link calls jQuery instead of going to page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Django site right now and every time I click a link, I get a jQuery error in my console instead of the page changing.

Line of Python in Django template (where i is a Page object, i.pageURL is a single word used to find the page, and i.pageTitle is a title (irrelevant): `<a data-toggle='tab' href="{% url 'pages_custom_page' p=i.pageURL %}">{{i.pageTitle}}</a>`
Line of HTML: `<a data-toggle="tab" href="/about/">About</a>`
Console: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /about/`

Any help? What other information can I give to help with this?

**EDIT:** I found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615272/linking-bootstrap-tabs-to-server-urls) that 'you can't use `/` because Bootstrap uses it as a selector'. Can anyone explain what this means and how I can avoid it?

**EDIT2:** I created a test with the following code:

```
<a data-toggle='tab' href="about">about</a>
<a data-toggle='tab' href="about/">about/</a>
<a data-toggle='tab' href="/about">/about</a>
<a data-toggle='tab' href="/about/">/about/</a>
```

and I found that the only one that doesn't raise an error in the console is the very first one (with no slashes - `<a data-toggle='tab' href="about">about</a>`). However, it still doesn't redirect when I click it, it essentially just ignores the click. Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - when I took `data-toggle='tab'` out of the tag, things worked perfectly!